# Kotlin async task/Firebase query, best method to wait for result?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Firstly, apologies as Im almost certain this has been asked before but I'm running in circles with answers I discover for this.

My issue is I am getting a response from a firebase query in my android app, however as I've discovered it's asynchronous and therefore I'm having trouble checking if my response contains any data or not.

Now for a solution for this I've discovered coroutines in Kotlin, these seem like the way to go but so far I haven't been able to get them to work. After getting some assitance today I was told to look into this, async task https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/AsyncTask however as far as I can tell these are depreciated in favour of coroutines so I feel like I'm back to square one.

I have seen that there are uses of `.async()` and `.await()` with corotuines but have had as much luck with them as I have with what is shown below.

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
private fun gotoSuccessActivity(){

            helper.currentUserID = auth.currentUser?.uid
            helper.checkForExistingUser() //where the coroutine starts

            val dependantUsersList:MutableList<UserEntry> = helper.dependantResultsArray

            if (dependantUsersList.isNotEmpty()) {
                //do stuff when there are associated users
            } else {
                //do stuff when there are no associated users
            }
        }
```

**Helper.kt**

```
fun checkForExistingUser() {
//check for main user
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{ checkForDependants() //check for associated users}
}

private suspend fun checkForDependants() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

//get associated user data

}
}
```

I've taken out all of the other code to try and simplify things, I know all that code works as the app runs fine all I'm trying to do is get it to wait for the response from `checkForDependants` before doing the `isNotEmpty` check.

I'm using a seperate Helper.kt file as I've been trying to make the code as reusable as possible, not for any other reason so this may be the wrong approach.

Any directions/resources I should look at to see how I should be looking to implement this properly is apreciated, thanks.

**Edit**

Ok so after seeing Stachu's answer I went back and tried to implement it with no more luck. However this did get me thinking differently and I was able to use it with my network check which was also using coroutines. Don't know why I didnt think about returned values but oh well.

Now I've also worked out a solution for my original problem, if its messy feel free to tell me but at least it works.

So, the issue (as far as i can see it) is that as I said the firebase queries are asyncronous and I was then trying to force them to behave more syncrounously using coroutines, this was doing nothing as it was just causing it to be 1 async task inside another. This is why trying to get the result from when the coroutine ended was doing nothing as it finishes when it starts the query.

The solution was therefore to get rid of the coroutine and instead restructure to use the built in handlers from firebase. Instead of trying to wait for a response then doing my check I just moved the check inside of the .addOnCompleteListener.

**LoginActivity.kt**

New function to hold the old check

```
 private fun filterForDependants(){
        val dependantUsersList: MutableList<UserEntry> = helper.dependantResultsArray
        if (dependantUsersList.isNotEmpty()) {
}
        else{}
}

private fun checkForDependants(){
//moved from the helper file mainly just to allow startActivityForResult() to work easier

firebasequery.addOnCompleteListener{
       filterForDependants() //the check is now only started after the query has completed
}
}

private fun gotoSuccessActivity() {
            findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar).isVisible = true
//used to provide user with feedback that work is ongoing
            helper.currentUserID = auth.currentUser?.uid
            helper.checkForExistingUser()
            checkForDependants() 
//I added it as its own method for consistency and so that i didnt need to refactor gotoSuccessActivity() everywhere it had been used.
        }
```

I hope that explained it well enough, I didn't want to leave the question open ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not processing the associated users in the same coroutine scope? `checkForExistingUser` and `checkForDependants` can return values, so you can do something like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun checkForExistingUser(): MutableList<UserEntry> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    checkForDependants() //check for associated users}
}

private suspend fun checkForDependants(): MutableList<UserEntry> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    //get associated user data
}
```

and then

```kotlin
private fun gotoSuccessActivity(){
    helper.currentUserID = auth.currentUser?.uid
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val dependantUsersList: MutableList<UserEntry> = helper.checkForExistingUser() //where the coroutine starts
        if (dependantUsersList.isNotEmpty()) {
            //do stuff when there are associated users
        } else {
            //do stuff when there are no associated users
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input I think I was doing something really stupid but this helped me solve another problem with coroutines I was having I've tried to explain how I fixed the original problem in an edit.

I'll just mark this as the solution as it helped. :)